# Angular bind to filtered count

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have this array:

```
[
    {
      type: "hhh",
      items: [
        {
          "name": "EGFR",
          "type": "a",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "aaa",
      items: [
        {
          "name": "mm",
          "type": "b",
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "ii",
      items: [
        {
          "name": "pp",
          "type": "bb",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to show a counter of the items with selected property "true".
I want it to be changed real time when change.
(Without watch and function)

Thnaks!

Comment: How is the array gonna be changed? Thru any back-end calls/Ajaz/API etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:

```
var current_selected = {
get amount(){
    var res = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
      if (item.items[0].selected) res++;
      })
      return res;
  }
}
```

Calling:

```
current_selected.amount
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/z8kk9tys/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonPath to get the count. Also using JsonPath has an added advantage of working on complex json structure. For the example you gave, you just need to include jsonpath js file and use the following in your script:

```
console.log(arr);
var filtered = jsonPath(arr, "$.[*].items[?(@.selected==true)]");
console.log(filtered);
console.log(filtered.length);
```

where arr is your json structure.

JsonPath can be got from :
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads

JsonPath help:
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

*There might be updated version in other sources but that was the one I had worked on*